# Poor performance for POCO Generator

Tags: c#, entity-framework, poco, t4

I am working on a Legacy application, and we have a poor performance with Entity Framework (4.0.0) and massive insert.

When I tried the POCO Generator (T4), the issue was worse, the SaveChanges was three times longer. This is huge, if you have any idea why I have this issue, I am interested.

Comment: ORMs are not intended for "massive inserts". Use pure SQL.

Comment: I know that, I am not orm-fan, but the Legacy application use this and have a very big Model, the batch and the application use the same domain, I can't rapidely Improve this strategy... I don't like this, but I have to deal with it initialy. Thanks for your comment

Comment: Without code we can't see if there are any obvious performance hits.

Comment: BTW I have the same issue if I monitor the operation with a little set of data... @GertArnold my question is about a general review of performance about POCO Generator vs Entity Object

Comment: With POCO the metadata and the mappings must be generated at runtime, that's all. This is a one-time operation because the model is cached. So you should notice it the first time a context interacts with the database. But that's only about the difference between _poor_ and _worse_.

Comment: As others said, massive inserts is not a good call for ORM. Anyway, if you call `DetectChanges` just before `SaveChanges`, how long does the `DetectChanges` take?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any performance metrics for different generators.  But the bottleneck should not be in your context anyway.  You should know EF will generate one SQL statement per insert, update and delete, and if you didn't explicitly open the connection first, it will log on before and log off from sql server once per SQL statement.

Also the context must maintain the states and relationships so the performance degrades as your context gets larger and larger.  SaveChanges must figure out what's happening in the context first and should be the reason why POCO Generator vs Entity Object ends up with different execution times.  As far as it being 3 times longer, more details will be needed to figure it out.

PS, if you are stuck with the legacy code, you should look into using bulk copy with EF.